# Swift PickerView shows nothing, no action no list

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am a newbie in swift. I am sure I have missed something really basic. I am trying to initialise a `PickerView` in my view, for some reason the list does not show. Nothing happens when I click the picker too. What am I missing ?

Strangely why dont `PickerView's` have `ID's` like `Label` or a `TextView`

[image]

Here is the ViewController code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var pickerView = UIPickerView()
    var pickerDataSource = ["White", "Red", "Green", "Blue"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initialization for Country Code pickerView
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.isHidden = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Methods for Country Code pickerView
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerDataSource.count;
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerDataSource[row]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I realized that I had the IBOutlet missing. To add it I followed the instructions below. But, now if I drag and try to drop into my `Viewcontroller` the popup never shows.

Also, I added this line manually, still it does not work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried to drag drop the OutLet to the ViewController. For some reason I am now getting `Exception`

> check the image below top right, you will notice `delegate` and 'datasource` to the View. Is this ok ?

[image]

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa3a40a900'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dce8d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d74a21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd58f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc6e005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc6db88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010e0ec20f -[UIPickerView _delegateNumberOfComponents] + 56
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010e0eb33b -[UIPickerView _updateSelectedRows] + 91
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010e0eb40a -[UIPickerView didMoveToWindow] + 102
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010e1cb256 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1799
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010e1cae82 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 819
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010e1cae82 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 819
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010e1bdfea __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010e1bded8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 857
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e1cde56 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1982
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010e1bc0d7 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 838
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010e5d0fdb -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 645
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010e2f095b -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3314
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010e2f0ef9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 874
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010e2f1fdb -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010e4e8dd7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010e1d1ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000011368bbf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000011367f440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000011367f2be _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    24  QuartzCore                          0x000000011360d318 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    25  QuartzCore                          0x000000011363a3ff _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    26  QuartzCore                          0x000000011363ad6f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc8d267 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc8d1d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc718a6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 454
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010e106aea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010e10cc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    32  BuzTransit                          0x000000010cdb5bbf main + 111
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114ce368d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**EDIT 2**

I have connected my picker to the `View Controller` correctly now.

[image]

But I think my `pickerView` is still not connected properly. Notice the image below, I am guessing that the circle should be marked with a fat dot. As I said the drag drop from picker to `ViewController.swift` just does not work.

**EDIT 4**

I had to restart Xcode and mention the ViewController name to my StoryBoard. These 2 things I was then able to drag drop a IBOutlet from my storyboard to the view controller. And the circle with a FAT DOT finally connected in my ViewController.

[image]

Comment: Create IBOutlet for the UIPickerView in storyboard.

Comment: are you created the pickerview in progrmatically

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No, I have not created the PickerView programmatically, I dragged it and dropped it on the storyboard.

Comment: @Siddharth You have to create IBOutlet of pickerview. Check this it will helps you to create IBOutlet. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: @Siddharth In the example they have created the IBOutlet of textField you have to do same with pickerView.

Comment: but this line is `var pickerView = UIPickerView()` created by progrmatically not connected from storyboard

Comment: I think I need to create using IBOutlet. that is the mistake..

Comment: You can check this video too. http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2016/3/1/60-how-to-create-outlets-and-actions-in-xcode-using-swift

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Check he created Picker in storyboard as he is new in iOS so he think doing this `var pickerView = UIPickerView()` will automatically connect the picker with storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Click the Assistant Editor button and make sure that the storyboard is in the left pane and that ViewController.swift is in the right.
>
> Then hold down control and click the UIPickerView element in the storyboard and drag your mouse over to the right side. Drop it in between the class ViewController and override func viewDidLoad.

[image]

> A small dialog will pop up to ask you for a name for this IBOutlet property. Just name it “picker”.

[image]

> After doing that, your ViewController.swift file will look like this:

[image]

> In ViewController.swift, add the following code.

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource  {

   @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

 var pickerDataSource: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     // Connect data:
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self
    
    // Input data into the Array:
    pickerDataSource = ["White", "Red", "Green", "Blue"]
}
```

then connect the datasource and delegate

```
// Methods for Country Code pickerView
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.count;
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDataSource[row]
}
```

for sample you can get the [tutorial here](http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/)

**update the error status**

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faa3a40a900'

Ans : it means your picker view not connected properly to your current class.

wrong Connection

you are connected to view

[image]

correct one is you need to connect with your files owner

[image]

Comment: I am clicking the "Cntrl" button and drag dropping, a blue line appears, but that popup does not appear.

Comment: @Siddharth - finally you need to press connect button

Comment: "connect" button ?

Comment: Drop above `func viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @RajeshkumarR - yes, I clearly added the image preview also

Comment: yeah, I dropped above the viewdidLoad. Still did not show the pop up

Comment: @Siddharth - can you update the question based on my answer, e

Comment: @Siddharth - at the same time check the array creation type

Comment: I have updated the question based on the answer. Sorry did not understand "array creation type"

Comment: @Siddharth - are you attach the project i will check

Comment: How do I attach the project ? Zip it and attach it ?

Comment: When I select the "PickerView" I get Outlets with empty datasource and delegate, the circles are empty.

Comment: @Siddharth -problem is some where else , attach in drop box and give the link

Comment: check my edit, if this does not give you more hints to the issue, I'll do that.

Comment: @Siddharth - ya i found the mistake , wait i update answer

Comment: @Siddharth - what happened my bro, at the same time your pickerview is not connected your current View Controller

Comment: yeah fixed that, now it links to "Registration".. still i get `app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdacb60d2f0'`

Comment: @Siddharth - your pickerview is connected or not bro, if it is connected surely worjs

Comment: @Siddharth - your problem is solved or not, I am waiting bro,

Comment: Edited my question again. I think when u say "pickerView" is connected you mean that the circle on the IBOutlet line should show a fat dot inside right ?

Comment: @Siddharth- yes , but still your picker view is not connected,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137566/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-siddharth).